# How to add folder in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I tried to add a new folder in android studio, but It hasn't created. 
I click right mouse button on res folder -> new -> Android Resource directory (or just a directory) ->
write a name and click enter, but there is no new folder in android studio explorer. 
When I check res folder in windows explorer I found, that these folders are created, but I can't see them In android studio. 
Honestly, I tried to create layout-large firstly, but then I discovered, that there is no way to see created folders in android studio.
What can it be? How can I fix this problem? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you try clean build, then File > Invalidate and restart, then after that Rebuild/Make project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to see the created folders switch your project view from `Android` view to `Project` from the dropdown menu in order to see them. Android view allows you to see the default Android project resource folders only, any additional folders will not be recognized by the `Android` view.

[image]